# join array enclosing each value with quotes javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can join an array into a string and at the same time enclosing each value into this

> '1/2/12','15/5/12'

```
for (var i in array) {
    dateArray.push(array[i].date);
}
dateString=dateArray.join('');
console.log(dateString);
```

Comment: Push the dates with quotes around it?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to wrap each entry in quotes and then join them.

```js
var dates = ['1/2/12','15/5/12'];
const datesWrappedInQuotes = dates.map(date => `'${date}'`);
const withCommasInBetween = datesWrappedInQuotes.join(',')
console.log( withCommasInBetween );
```

Comment: your map solution is good but it is best to use each function in this case. Thanks.

Comment: @Avnishalok It's best to provide reasoning for your preference. Or even better provide your own answer and let others decide.

Answer (score 22):

ES6:

```js
const dates = ['1/2/12','15/5/12'];
const result = dates.map(d => `'${d}'`).join();

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
dateString = '\'' + dateArray.join('\',\'') + '\'';
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mLRMb/

Comment: my first post was: dateString = "'" + dateArray.join("','") + "'"; I just changed the double quotes to single ones.

Comment: its working man.but what am trying to do is to put this string inside the categories empty object in highcharts (chart library), but the chart wont display the dates. i dont know why

Comment: @angelos, then you should make a different question.

Comment: @PedroL. It's much easier to understand if you don't use escape sequences if you can.