# Join a JavaScript array with double quotes

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to join a list of `latLng` values which are stored in an array like this:

```
"48.2025,16.3687","48.2437,16.3797"
```

Instead, I keep getting output like this:

```
"48.2025,16.3687,48.2437,16.3797"
```

This is the code that I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {

    $('#printMapLatLng').click(function()

        {
            var printPoints = [];
            for (var i in points) {
                var input = points[i].LatLng.toString();
                var output = ''+input.replace( /\s/g, "").slice(1,-1)+'';
                printPoints.push(output);
            }         
                var fullArray = printPoints.join();
                $(this).attr('href',PowerHour.getPrintUrl([fullArray]));
        });
});
```

Comment: points.map(function(x){ return '"'+x+'"';}).join(",");

Comment: What is the expected result? A nested array containing an array of the pair of coordinates in each "row"?

Comment: `var output = ''+input.replace( /\s/g, "").slice(1,-1)+'';` What’s this supposed to do?

Comment: remove the brackets and the white spaces from the latLng value pair

Comment: @KelumAnthony There's no brackets or whitespaces in your example. Is this `points` actually a string rather than an array? Please add an expected result in your question, now you just say: `instead I keep getting output like this.` Instead of what?

Comment: @Teemu var input = points[i].LatLng.toString();  returns something like this (48.2025, 16.3687)

Comment: @KelumAnthony So, it's an array. But what you expect to be the final result? 1D- or 2D-array? Also you should not iterate an array with `for..in`, it will lead to unexpected results. Always use a regular `for` loop to iterate arrays.

Comment: the final out put is supposed to be a 1D array. okay i will try a regular for loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [join array enclosing each value with quotes javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769774/join-array-enclosing-each-value-with-quotes-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

If you want single line, use this:

```js
const values = ["48.2025,16.3687", "48.2437,16.3797"];

console.log(values.map(value => `"${value}"`).join());
```

Answer (score 2):

This should help :)

```
var points = ["48.2025,16.3687","48.2437,16.3797"];
points.map(function(p){ return '"' + p + '"'; }).join(',');
// => '"48.2025,16.3687","48.2437,16.3797"'
```

Comment: Looks like OP has an array like this: `["48.2025,16.3687","48.2437,16.3797"]`, maybe it's better not to change that fact?

Comment: @minitech Yep, with the array in the answer, the result is 1D -array, with the array in the question, the result is 2D-array : (.

Comment: @Teemu, sorry I didn't see that; I updated my post. The solution is still identical, though :)

Comment: @naomik Please check OP's last comment below the question, OP seems to want an 1D-array, probably with types of numbers in it too, he didn't tell...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this to get the output

```
var fullArray = "\"" + printPoints.join("\",\"") + "\"";
```

Comment: You could also forgo the escaping by using different quotes: `var fullArray = '"' + printPoints.join('", "') + '"';`

Comment: yeah i have 2 more extra quotes. any solution ?