# Passing an array in an http request

Tags: angular

`this.brandsId` is an array of numbers.

```
private fetchData() {
 this.service.get(this.tabIndex, dateStart, dateEnd, this.brandsId).subscribe(data => {
  some code
 });
}
```

**service:**

```
public get(
 from_date?: string,
 to_date?: string,
 brands_ids?: any,
 ): Observable<any> {
 let params = new HttpParams()
 .set('123', from_date)

 if(brands_ids) {
  console.log(brands_ids) ---> still array (like [1, 2, 3])
  params = params.set('brands_ids', brands_ids);
 }

 return this.http
 .get<any>(`APIURL`, {params})   ---> somehow transform to string.(like 1, 2, 3)
 .pipe(catchError(error => throwError((error?.error?.errors) || error)));
 }
```

What do I need to change?

Comment: Angular already supports passing arrays as HTTP params. Just check your request and you should see them. But since there's no set way of passing them, you can have some unwanted syntax. In that case, you need to parse it yourself. And if you want help on that, then you need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: i suggest you use a post query

Answer (score 0):

We could use the `join()` https://stackoverflow.com/a/11769811/15439733 method to transform an array of numbers into a string with comma-separated values and append `brands_ids` to HttpParams? https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams#append Difference between `.set` and `.append` is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51981150/15439733

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  API_URL = '/v1/demo';
  requestUrl;
  from_date = '2023-03-29T14:08:59+00:00';
  brands_ids = [1, 2, 3];

  newParams = new HttpParams();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.newParams = this.get(this.from_date, null, this.brands_ids);

    this.requestUrl = this.http
      .get(this.API_URL, { params: this.newParams })
      .pipe(catchError((error) => of(error.url)));
  }

  public get(from_date?: string, to_date?: string, brands_ids?: any) {
    let params = new HttpParams().set('123', from_date);

    if (brands_ids) {
      console.log(this.brands_ids.join(','));
      params = new HttpParams({
        fromObject: { '123': from_date, brands_ids: this.brands_ids.join(',') },
      });
    }

    return params;
  }
}
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-httpparams-9ccc2r?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts